# How do I remove the error in the workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064, workbench

Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')
ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 10
SQL Code:

```
 -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `limpieza_es`.`datos_comun`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `limpieza_es`.`datos_comun` (
          `Nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `Email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `Mensaje` TEXT NOT NULL,
          `Tel` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`Email`),
          UNIQUE INDEX `Tel` (`Tel` ASC) VISIBLE)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: Read this issue: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92269.

Answer (score 0):

**Visible is not known** in Mariadb **invisible** does, but even this you cannot use at that position.

So make simple

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `limpieza_es`.`datos_comun` (
      `Nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `Email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `Mensaje` TEXT NOT NULL,
      `Tel` INT(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`Email`),
      UNIQUE INDEX `Tel` (`Tel` ASC) )
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

here the link to Mariadb and invisible columns https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/invisible-columns/